# Make an IEnumerable from class

Tags: c#

I have two classes "Word.cs" and "TrainerFile.cs". The TrainerFile contains a collection of 5 different `List<Word>`, and a Word contains the 2 strings Lang1 and Lang2. What I need is a List or enum for all the words inside a TrainerFile, so that i can make a random list of the words of said TrainerFile. I have no idea how to access all the words. Here is the 2 classes:

```
public class Word
{
    public string Lang1 { get; set; }
    public string Lang2 { get; set; }

    public Word()
    {
        this.Lang1 = "";
        this.Lang2 = "";
    }

    public Word(string lang1, string lang2)
    {
        this.Lang1 = lang1;
        this.Lang2 = lang2;
    }
}

public class TrainerFile
{
    public List<Word> FolderInitial { get; set; }
    public List<Word> Folder1 { get; set; }
    public List<Word> Folder2 { get; set; }
    public List<Word> Folder3 { get; set; }
    public List<Word> FolderFinal { get; set; }

    public TrainerFile()
    {
        this.FolderInitial = new List<Word>();
        this.Folder1 = new List<Word>();
        this.Folder2 = new List<Word>();
        this.Folder3 = new List<Word>();
        this.FolderFinal = new List<Word>();
    }

    public TrainerFile(List<Word> listInitial, List<Word> list1, List<Word> list2, List<Word> list3, List<Word> listFinal)
    {
        this.FolderInitial = listInitial;
        this.Folder1 = list1;
        this.Folder2 = list2;
        this.Folder3 = list3;
        this.FolderFinal = listFinal;
    }
}
```

Comment: You want a single list containing all the items from the 5 lists?

Comment: You should probably use a dictionary of lists.

Comment: @Gilad Green: yes exactly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use linq's [`Concat`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb302894(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var result = FolderInitial.Concat(Folder1)
                          .Concat(Folder2)
                          .Concat(Folder3)
                          .Concat(FolderFinal);
```

- If you want a distinct list then when instead of using `Concat` use
  [`Union`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341731(v=vs.110).aspx) and override the `Word` class's `Equals` and `GetHashCode` methods to compare by the properties of the class.
- Another way instead of overriding the methods is supplying an [`IEqualityComparer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151(v=vs.110).aspx) of [this overload of `Union`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358407(v=vs.110).aspx)

---

Also, since C# 6.0, instead of having the default constructor you can:

```
public class TrainerFile
{
    public List<Word> FolderInitial { get; set; } = new List<Word>();
    public List<Word> Folder1 { get; set; } = new List<Word>();
    public List<Word> Folder2 { get; set; } = new List<Word>();
    public List<Word> Folder3 { get; set; } = new List<Word>();
    public List<Word> FolderFinal { get; set; } = new List<Word>();
}
```

Comment: @GiladGreen: I've found 20 such comments of yours in the past 3 months alone. Please stop asking for downvoters to explain themselves, see [Why isn't commenting mandatory on downvotes, and why are ideas suggesting such shot down?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/357436) for why requiring that someone comments is not ever going to be mantadory.

Comment: @GiladGreen: as for directly pinging users that you think might have voted; that is really not constructive and needs to stop entirely.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like a case for a `Dictionary<string, List<Word>>`

```
Dictionary<string, List<Word>> trainerFile = new Dictionary<string, List<Word>>();
trainerFile.Add("FolderInitial", new List<Word>());
trainerFile.Add("Folder1", new List<Word>());
trainerFile.Add("Folder2", new List<Word>());
trainerFile.Add("Folder3", new List<Word>());
trainerFile.Add("FolderFinal", new List<Word>());
```

Then access like so:

```
List<string> initial = trainerFile["FolderInitial"];
trainerFile["Folder2"].Add(new Word());
Word word = trainerFile["Folder2"][0];
```

To access every single word,

```
IEnumerable<Word> all = trainerFile.Values.SelectMany(i => i);
```

Comment: I don't see why the dictionary is needed at all.  You can concat all the values together without it.

Comment: This is great, I didn't know what a dictionary was. Gilad Greens shorter answer did the trick for me though.

Comment: @Amy because it is better for expandability and future supporting. Imagine having a class with 50+ folders. And imagine that concat statement. With dictionary, the line `trainerFile.Values.SelectMany(i => i)` is always short and sweet, and doesn't change when you add more folders.

Comment: @SamFisher39 his answer only seems shorter, but my answer actually shortens your overall code, because it scraps and replaces your class, which will only get larger when you add more folders. Also his answer won't be so short anymore with more folders.